# Search for a capital letter in a string and move the cursor to it

Tags: regular-expressions, search

I am trying to learn how to implement regular expressions in emacs. I have a string that looks like this:

```
Fname0 Mname0 Surname0Fname1 Surname1Fname2
```

I would like to search for any capital letter and move the cursor to it. How do I go about doing that? I would later like to insert space and a comma in that spot.

Comment: highly recommend to install and use [visual-regexp](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el) to build and replace regex visually, see the nice gif in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an interactive regexp search via the command `isearch-forward-regexp`, bound to `M-C-s` by default.

You can search for any upper-case letter via `[A-Z]`, or `[[:upper:]]`. This will take you to the first capital after point. Pressing `C-s` will move to the next, which you can repeat.

To do this from elisp code, you can use the function `search-forward-regexp`.

Your question is very general, so it's hard to tell how familiar you are with Emacs and elisp code in general. If you're new to elisp, the [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/) might be useful. If you have some experience and just need to get oriented to Emacs/elisp, then the manual chapter on [Searching and Replacing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-and-Matching.html) might be what you're after.